# Looping thru file types and attaching them into email

Tags: python

I have a list of text files and html files generated by two distinct functions. Each file is labeled signal1.txt, signal2, etc. and signal1.html, signal2.html, etc. I need to send an email with each file pair (signal1.txt and signal1.html, signal2.txt and signal.2.html, and so forth).

I've tried several different ways, but I keep getting just one file pair attached (the last file number whatever it is) over and over. I have no problem sending one file type, but it gets messy when I try with two different files. I'd like to give you as much info as possible and perhaps enough reproducible code for you to try it out on your end if you wish, so my apologies for the long question.

The data is collected from the server. The final result is sorted using the Counter module:

```
data = Counter({('A user account was locked out ', 47, 'medium', 25): 1, ('An attempt was made to reset an accounts password ', 73, 'high', 2): 1, ('PowerShell Keylogging Script', 73, 'high', 37): 1, ('PowerShell Suspicious Script with Audio Capture Capabilities', 47, 'medium', 36): 1})
```

I need the rule name to be used in the email subject, so everything else is junk. For instance, in `('A user account was locked out ', 47, 'medium', 25): 1`, I only need `A user account was locked out`. So the following function takes care of all that:

```
def create_txt_files():
    global regex
    global count
    count = 0

    #Convert dict into string and remove unwanted chars
    for signal in dict(event_dict).keys():
        indiv_signal = (str(signal).replace(",",'').replace('(','').replace(')','')\
                        .replace("'",'').replace('[','').replace(']',''))
        #Further removal of debris using regex
        pattern = '^(\D*)'
        regex = ''.join(re.findall(pattern,indiv_signal,re.MULTILINE))
        count +=1
        with open(f"signal{count}.txt", "w") as fh:
            fh.write(str(regex))
create_txt_files()
```

I also need to create html files that will go in the body of the email as a Dataframe. In this case I need almost all the fields in the data file. The dataframe should look like this:

```
                            Alert Score Risk Severity Total
0  A user account was locked out          47   medium    26
```

The following function takes care of that:

```
#Create Individual HTML files
def create_indiv_html_files():
    global html_file
    global count
    count = 0

    #Turn rows into columns
    for items in list(event_dict):
        df = pd.DataFrame(items)
        new_df = df.transpose()
        new_df.columns = ['Alert','Score Risk','Severity','Total']
        html_file = new_df.to_html()
        print(new_df)
        count +=1
        with open(f'signal{count}.html','w') as wf:
            wf.write(html_file)
create_indiv_html_files()
```

So, up to this point everything is fine and dandy, albeit not as pretty a code as I'd like. But it works, and that's all I'm worried about now. The problem is that when I send the email, I'm getting only one rule (the last one) sent over and over. It's not iterating over the txt and html files and attaching them as it should.

[image]

Here is the email function I'm using. Despite my several different attempts, I still have not been able to figure out what's wrong. Thank you for taking the time to help.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
import smtplib, ssl
import os

dirname = r'C:\Path\To\Files'
ext = ('.txt','html')

for files in os.scandir(dirname):
    if files.path.endswith(ext):

        def sendmail():
            html_body = '''
            <html>
                <body>
                    <p style="font-size: 12;"> <strong>Alert</strong><br>{html_file}</p>
                </body>
            </html>
            '''.format(html_file=html_file)

            subject = f'Alert: {regex} '
            senders_email = 'mail@mail.comt'
            receiver_email = 'mail@mail.comt'

            # Create a multipart message and set headers
            message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            message['From'] = senders_email
            message['To'] = receiver_email
            message['Subject'] = subject

            #Attach email body
            message.attach(MIMEText(html_body, 'html'))

            # Name of the file to be attached
            filename = f'signal{count}.html'

            # Open file in binary mode
            with open(filename, 'rb') as attachment:
                # Add file as application/octet-stream
                part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
                part.set_payload(attachment.read())

            # Encodes file in ASCII characters to send via email
            encoders.encode_base64(part)

            # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
            part.add_header(
                'Content-Disposition',
                f"attachment; filename= {filename}",

            )

            # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
            message.attach(part)
            text = message.as_string()

            # Log into server using secure connection
            context = ssl.create_default_context()
            with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.com", 25) as server:
                # server.starttls(context=context)
                # server.login(senders_email, 'password')
                server.sendmail(senders_email, receiver_email, text)
            print("Email sent!")
        sendmail()
```

Comment: You are not updating the count variable in sendmail function

Comment: @darthbaba Hey, thanks for chiming in. Could you be more specific, please? If you mean adding a count +=1 under the for loop, it won't recognize the variable even if it's global. And if I instantiate the count = 0 variable again before the for loop, it will still repeat the same alert over and over, but now it gives an error in the end because it looks for a signal5.html, which doesnt exist. If you mean something else, let me know. You can post your answer as well, it's easier to see what you mean.

Comment: Where are you attaching the .txt files?

Comment: @darthbaba txt files go in the email subject and use the regex variable

Comment: One last question what is html_file? that you are using in the str format html_body? is it a DataFrame?

Comment: @darthbaba Sort of. This variable holds the .to_html() function in the create_html_files() function. html_file = new_df.to_html()

Apparently, you need a variable in the <html> frame in the email body.
<p style="font-size: 12;"> <strong>Alert</strong><br>{html_file}</p>

So, that's what the html_variable is for. I had to instantiate it and pass the new_df.to_html() value into it:

html_file = new_df.to_html()

I hope that makes sense...

Comment: It's quite odd that the definition of the `sendmail()` function is inside the for loop.  Do you really need to define the sendmail function 20 times?

Comment: @darthbaba Working on it. Will let you know.

Comment: @JohnGordon Hey, I don't know how else to do it if not by iterating over every file. How would you approach this?

Comment: It's normal to _call_ the sendmail function once per file in a loop.  It's not normal to _define_ the function once per file in a loop.  I mean, I guess it doesn't hurt anything.  But it's weird, and it suggests that you don't really understand what's going on.

Comment: @JohnGordon I actually DO understand the function is being called repeatdly. As I said, I dont know how else to do it. Instead of criticizing, either help or don't bother writing. Thanks.

Comment: `def sendmail()` is inside the loop.  Therefore the function is _defined_, over and over, each time the loop executes.  This is an odd way to do things.  I thought you would appreciate someone pointing out that your code is odd.  My mistake.

Comment: @JohnGordon I definitely appreciate your taking the time to answer. What I meant is that I know this is what is going on and that I don't know how else to do it if not by throwing it into the for loop. I also asked how you would approach it, but you just point the obvious saying I don't know. So, how about we start this convo afresh?

Comment: Move the function definition somewhere else, above the for loop.  Only the _call_ to the function belongs inside the loop.  But again, this is not the cause of your reported problem; this is only a side issue.

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh, I see... yeah for sure... I'm just trying to get this thing to work. Once it's fully functional, I'm going to refactor the whole thing, clean up, and make it look more presentable. It's an eyesore for now. In fact, I want to move the email function into its own file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the code and removed the global variables. Below code should work let me know if you get any errors.

```
import pathlib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
import smtplib, ssl
import os


def create_txt_files(event_dict):
    regex = []
    count = 0

    #Convert dict into string and remove unwanted chars
    for signal in dict(event_dict).keys():
        indiv_signal = (str(signal).replace(",",'').replace('(','').replace(')','')\
                        .replace("'",'').replace('[','').replace(']',''))
        #Further removal of debris using regex
        pattern = '^(\D*)'
        regex.append(''.join(re.findall(pattern,indiv_signal,re.MULTILINE)))
        count +=1
        with open(f"signal{count}.txt", "w") as fh:
            fh.write(str(regex[0]))

    return regex

def create_indiv_html_files(event_dict):
    html_file = []
    count = 0

    #Turn rows into columns
    for items in list(event_dict):
        df = pd.DataFrame(items)
        new_df = df.transpose()
        new_df.columns = ['Alert','Score Risk','Severity','Total']
        html_file.append(new_df.to_html())
        print(new_df)
        count +=1
        with open(f'signal{count}.html','w') as wf:
            wf.write(html_file[0])

    return html_file

def sendmail(html_file, regex, path_html):
    html_body = '''
    <html>
        <body>
            <p style="font-size: 12;"> <strong>Alert</strong><br>{html_file}</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    '''.format(html_file=html_file)

    subject = f'Alert: {regex} '
    senders_email = 'mail@mail.comt'
    receiver_email = 'mail@mail.comt'

    # Create a multipart message and set headers
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    message['From'] = senders_email
    message['To'] = receiver_email
    message['Subject'] = subject

    #Attach email body
    message.attach(MIMEText(html_body, 'html'))

    # Name of the file to be attached
    # filename = f'signal{count}.html'

    # Open file in binary mode
    with open(path_html, 'rb') as attachment:
        # Add file as application/octet-stream
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(attachment.read())

    # Encodes file in ASCII characters to send via email
    encoders.encode_base64(part)

    # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
    part.add_header(
        'Content-Disposition',
        f"attachment; filename= {path_html.name}",

    )

    # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
    message.attach(part)
    text = message.as_string()

    # Log into server using secure connection
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.com", 25) as server:
        # server.starttls(context=context)
        # server.login(senders_email, 'password')
        server.sendmail(senders_email, receiver_email, text)
    print("Email sent!")


data = Counter({('A user account was locked out ', 47, 'medium', 25): 1, ('An attempt was made to reset an accounts password ', 73, 'high', 2): 1, ('PowerShell Keylogging Script', 73, 'high', 37): 1, ('PowerShell Suspicious Script with Audio Capture Capabilities', 47, 'medium', 36): 1})
regex = create_txt_files(data)
html_file = create_indiv_html_files(data)

signalfiles = sorted(list(pathlib.Path('C:\Path\To\Files').glob('*.txt')))
htmlfiles = sorted(list(pathlib.Path('C:\Path\To\Files').glob('*.html')))

for i, path_html_file in enumerate(htmlfiles):
    sendmail(html_file[i], regex[i], path_html_file)
```

The create_txt_files and create_indiv_html_files takes input the Counter dictionary. Sendmail function will take in regex, html_file string and html_file path.

Comment: I get a TypeError (TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list) complaining about the create_indiv_html_files() function. It doesnt like the html_file = []. And changing it to a string will also produce an error because obviously there is no append for strings.

Comment: You just need to write the string that is stored in the list. I have edited the code

Comment: Thank you heaps! Thank you for taking the time to help.